# How to hide the options menu for only one column in MUI datagrid?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI x (community version) and I want to hide the options' menu from a particular column, not for all the columns. I still want the others to display this menu, but only for this column, I want to hide it. How?

`disableColumnMenu` disables it for all the columns.

```js
// const columns = [ ... etc, then eventually
{ field: 'actionMenu', headerName: strings.actions, sortable: false, filterable: false },
// ]
```

```js
<DataGrid
  disableSelectionOnClick
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  density="compact"
  loading={isLoading}
  components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
  localeText={{
    noRowsLabel: strings.noModerators,
  }}
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are very close.

Try this one in the field you want to hide the menu

```
{ 
  field: 'actionMenu', 
  headerName: strings.actions, 
  sortable: false, 
  filterable: false, 
  disableColumnMenu: true // This will hide it only for the Actions column
},
```

Also please have a look at this [working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-platform-igekjf?file=/demo.tsx), I am hiding the menu only for the 'Age' column and the rest they display the menu on hover

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to achieve what I was trying to achieve in the question, MUI provides a built-in way to create an *"actions"* column.

the columns with type `actions` have no column menu by default.

The *"actions column"* will include *"action cells"*, the action cells may have buttons, or maybe a menu button where you click and drop a listed menu with other buttons.

Using the built-in way is a better decision because it makes your *action column* compatible with the already built-in data grid filters.

To declare an action column, in your column definition, use the `type: 'actions'` property with the `getActions: (cell) => []` property, and with the `<GridActionsCellItem />` component, example:

```
export default function ProductsDataGrid() {
  const columns = [
    {
      field: "name",
      width: 200,
      type: "string",
    },
    {
      field: "price",
      width: 100,
      type: "number",
    },
    {
      field: "actions",
      type: "actions",
      width: 100,
      getActions: (cell) => [
        <GridActionsCellItem
          label="delete"
          icon={<DeleteIcon />}
          onClick={() => openDeleteModal(cell.row)}
        />,
      ],
    },
  ];

  const data = [{ name: "Egg", price: 20 }];

  return <DataGrid columns={columns} rows={data} autoHeight />;
}
```

This will result in showing a delete button inside a cell.

If you want it to show up inside the menu, just use the `showInMenu` prop:

```
 <GridActionsCellItem
  showInMenu
  label="delete"
  icon={<DeleteIcon />}
  onClick={() => openDeleteModal(cell.row)}
/>,
```

The `actions` column by default doesn't have a filter, and it won't show you the header actions.